# Подключение флешки к телефону с помощью компьютера

Tags: android, usb, драйвер, ос

Идея в том чтобы подключить телефон по usb и флешку к компьютеру и пользоваться флешкой на телефоне.
Существуют ли программы или драйверы для подобной затеи?
Или кто может подкинуть ссылку на материалы по теме usb и использование в языках программирования, не важно для какого языка, важно что-бы можно было заставить думать телефон что к нему подключена флешка как по otg-кабелю

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме.

Comment: почему бы вам не подключать флешку напрямую к телефону через переходнк?

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно всё, но очень дорого.

В 99 случаях из 100 обычный PC — всегда USB хост, а при подключении по обычному, не-OTG кабелю телефон — всегда периферия. Таким образом чтобы воплотить желаемое необходимо разработать:

1. Специальный драйвер для телефона.
2. Специальный драйвер для компьютера.
3. Протокол для их общения.

Готового почти наверняка ничего нет. Вероятно вместо разработки всего с нуля можно как-то модифицировать usb-storage. Но в любом случае ИМХО цель ни как не оправдывает средства.